# How to fix the error with the execution of the command for the bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a bot for discords. I decided to implement the command to play the video (music). There is a problem with a following code snippet:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_client = client.voice_clients(server)#< An error occurs here
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()
```

Namely: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. The title could also be improved.

Comment: @AMC, https://pastebin.com/e503g7kZ

Comment: That should go in the post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the line of

`client.voice_clients(server)`

Where you are calling the list object `client.voice_clients` (calling meaning, you're treating as a function, meaning you're using it with brackets).

To find the voice client of a specific server, do something like the following:

`voice_client = discord.utils.find(lambda c: c.guild.id == server.id, client.voice_clients)`

The `find` command is very useful for exactly this kind of stuff. [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.find)

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. But as I mentioned in the text, there is a problem on the problem. The problem now arises with this: `player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)`

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'`. 

I tried to import the module: `VoiceClient` (` from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient`). Did not help :(

Comment: I sadly don't know enough about voice clients to help you with that.

Comment: Okey. Thank. I'll think